# Ubuntu install with Nvidia graphics

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I want to install Ubuntu on a separate, fresh SSD. **Try Ubuntu** and **Install Ubuntu** gave me a black screen because of the graphics card. I pressed <kbd>e</kbd> and set `nomodeset` which allowed the stick to boot and I installed on the SSD.

On reboot, I changed `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` and now it just gives me a purple screen. I got in using recovery mode and installed the graphics drivers but it wanted me to restart and it still won't let me back in without going to recovery mode...

What should I do?

```
ii  libcuda1-375                                375.66-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-375                                  375.66-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.66
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                       375.66-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             381.22-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.8.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
^C
[1]-  Done                    dpkg -l | grep --color=auto -i nvidia
[2]+  Done                    dkms status
```

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Internal drive? How did you install nVidia driver? From Ubuntu repository or from nVidia (not recommended)?

Comment: You might want to remove the "SSD" from your title, that has nothing to do with the problem, and then you will get more relevant "Related" questions in the list in the right sidebar.

Comment: I believe it asked me to switch to UEFI, its an internal drive and I installed the driver from the ubuntu repo. @oldfred

Comment: If you installed the correct version for your nVidia card/chip then it should work ok. What card & what video driver and what version of Ubuntu? Post these: `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` & 
`dkms status` & 
`lsmod | grep nvidia`
`

Comment: I updated the origrinal post with the output. Thanks! @oldfred

Comment: You have bbswitch & 375 installed with kernel 4.8-51 and just 375 in kernel 4.4. I have previously suggested removing bbswitch as it is really only for some laptops, but some have had issues removing it as it also removes other files. I have this in my notes that someone posted. bbswitch issues with kernel 4.8 Boot parameter pcie_port_pm=off But not sure what else it does.